# no funciona el soundpool.stop

Tags: java, android-studio, sonido, soundpool

estoy intentando hacer que el sonido deje de sonar cuando el usuario deje de presionar (levante el dedo) pero no funciona, el sonido sigue de largo...

```
 Negra3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                soundPool.play(sonido3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

            } else if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                soundPool.stop();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

en la parte de `soundpool.stop();`  los parentesis me subraya en rojo, entonces pongo `soundpool.stop(sonido3);` no marca error pero al correr no funciona el stop, sino que el sonido sigue de largo... que debo hacer?, aclaro que si pongo `soundpool.autopause();` si funciona pero no me convence :(

Comment: Luis, ¿ como inicializas soundPool ?

Comment: le puse `private SoundPool soundPool;`  y luego en el mainactivity puse el constructor.. .

Comment: De hecho quería ver como lo inicializas.

Comment: y eso lo que comente no es inicializar?  jaja